# Setup a password. But now when entering the password it says wrong password

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, setup-assistant

I just bought a MacBook Air 11 inch, mid 2013 edition. When I started my MBA to go through the initial setup assistant, the voice over feature was on. So I learned how to go through with that but I was just entering my time zone when I got bored and put my MBA in sleep mode. When I opened it it asked me for my password. When I enter the password, it keeps saying it is wrong password. I think I was by able to finish the whole setup assistant also. I am very new to Mac. I have no idea how things are done.

Comment: Well, did you set up a password for wake up ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just pressing the return key when asked for a password? If there is no password set, OS X will still ask for a password to do some things, but still let you progress by pressing the return key without typing in the password.